# To get the Iterator running in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code sample, im pretty sure the first block should be placed in the main(), but where do I place the second block to make this Iterator example work?

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String> ( );
```

Where do i place this? Would I need to create a second class?

```
static void printAll(ArrayList myList)
{
    Iterator it = myList.iterator();
}
```

then there's this typical iterator pattern....is this in any way related to the second code block?

```
static void printAll(ArrayList myList)
{
    Iterator it = myList.iterator();
    Object temp;
    while( it.hasNext() )
    {
        temp = it.next();
        System.out.println( temp );
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question doesn't really seem to make sense. You can try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want to achieve, if you are asking how to pass your `ArrayList` (local variable in main) to the `printAll` method, do something like below:

```
public class XYZ {
  static void printAll(ArrayList myList)
  {
    Iterator it = myList.iterator();
    Object temp;
    while(it.hasNext() )
    {
      temp = it.next();
      System.out.println( temp );
    }
    return;
  }

  public static void main(String...args){

    List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String> ( );
    myList.add("Hello");
    myList.add("World");
    printAll(myList);//passing myList to printAll
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need the `return;` in the `printAll` method, but it doesn't hurt anything either.

Comment: Sorry about that, somehow I didn't see it while reading it. I'll just see myself out now.

Comment: @user133466 printAll is not a variable in your code, its a method

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're trying to use an interator?

You can do something like this, assuming you're on [Java 5](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/jett/sstamm/#_forin).

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String> ( );
// set up list... etc.

for(String currentString : myList) {
 System.out.println(currentString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are only useful if you need to remove some element of the collection while traversing it (using the `Iterator.remove()` method). Otherwise, just use a for-each loop.